# Elastic search to find index is empty or not with Java api

Tags: java, elasticsearch

Before am indexing the documents i want to check whether my index is empty or not. Which means, i just want to get the count of all the docments. If it returns `0` i want to proceed some action else i want to proceed some other action.

Am using Elastic Search 6.2.3 version with RestHighLevelClient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just run search query with size equal 0. Then you will have access to total number of hits, which means how many documents are in the index.

```
SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest("index_name"); 
SearchSourceBuilder searchBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder(); 
searchBuilder.query(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery()); 
searchBuilder.size(0);
searchRequest.source(searchBuilder); 

SearchResponse searchResponse = client.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
SearchHits hits = searchResponse.getHits();
long totalHits = hits.getTotalHits();
if(totalHits == 0) {
    // proceed
}
```